# how to debug android sdk code while debugging my app?

Tags: android, debugging

I am developing android app for a a couple of months and still in the learning process.
I often feel the need to drill down deeper into code for certain issues that don't make sense to me. For example when I see crashes in apps and the stack trace is shown,, containing SDK classes Looper etc...
So I was wondering if it is possible to debug through sdk code while debugging ?
currently I am writting for platform API 7 and 8. when we download the SDK is the source code SDK source accessible as well ? and if so can we debug it ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vogella gives a tutorial on how to do this. It is a plugin. So just click the [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSourceCode/article.html#eclipsesource).

It is the number 2 in the article.

Let me know if it helped. =)

Comment: I think the link in this answer is not valid anymore because Vogella  seems to have removed the section about that plugin